# XML parent and child node names are same

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datatable, dataset

I have json as

```
"revenue": {
    "revenue": "1758803"
}
```

and I converted above json into XML and it is converted as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<revenue>
    <revenue> 
        1758803 
    </revenue>
</revenue>
```

when I read XML using dataset then table column mapping is marked as hidden.
Please help to advice how I can avoid column mapping as hidden and mark as element.

```
dsXMLNodeList = new DataSet();
lstAJsonNodes = new List<string>();
dsXMLNodeList.ReadXml(TempUseLoc + 
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtAPITemplate.Text.Trim()) + ".xml");

foreach(DataTable dt in dsXMLNodeList.Tables)
{
    if (CheckTableElement(dt))
    {
        lstAJsonNodes.Add(dt.TableName);
    }
}
```

```
private bool CheckTableElement(DataTable dt)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (dc.ColumnMapping == MappingType.Element)
        {
            isValid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: please edit your original question to add code, rather than putting it in a comment